# How to get smooth mean curves in Pyplot

Tags: python, matplotlib, tensorboard

So Tensorboard has this nice smoothing feature where you can plot the original curves in shaded colors, and a smooth version on top in solid color:
[image]

How can I do this with Pyplot? This feature is key to spot the trends with the smoothed curves and the variance with the shaded original curves. Tensorboard is quite limited though, so I'd like to recreate the look in matplot lib. Any ideas?

Note I don't want to "interpolate" between the data points, there's too much variance.

Comment: You can filter the data, with a mean filter or something simple. Check out the functionality in scipy: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/signal.html

Comment: @Robert Milletich This can be accessed via pandas very easily: e.g.: if your data is in `df`: `df.rolling(10).mean()` https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.rolling.html

Comment: @SpghttCd yes indeed! I always forget all the analysis functionality that pandas has readily available!

Comment: @SpghttCd, I think that's it!! If you answer with an example, I'll accept it!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the `rolling`-object of pandas. With this you can define a window of certain size which rolls over your data and you can use it then for calculating mean, sum or whatever.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

t = np.linspace(0, 1.5*np.pi, 2500)
y = np.sin(t**2)+np.random.random(2500)*.6
df = pd.DataFrame(y)
plt.plot(df[0], 'lightblue', df[0].rolling(10).mean(), 'b')
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! However, now `plt.legend(loc='lower right')` recognizes an additional legend to show. How do we work around this?

Comment: Separating the two `plt.plot()` helped, but it would be nice to control the behavior right with `plt.legend()`. Didn't find useful one-liner options there.